# How to create ESRI ascii grid (.asc) from csv file in R

Tags: r, grid, ascii, gis

I have a .csv file of parameter with x and y coordinates. I want to save that parameter in ESRI ascii grid (.asc).

```
 x  y   cadmium
181072  333611  11.7
181025  333558  8.6
181165  333537  6.5
181298  333484  2.6
181307  333330  2.8
181390  333260  3
181165  333370  3.2
181027  333363  2.8
181060  333231  2.4
181232  333168  1.6
```

Comment: try the [Geographic Information Systemns (GIS) Forum](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/68226/patrik)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `export.asc()` function from the `adehabitat` package.

First let's create our demo dataframe and convert it into a matrix...

```
library(adehabitat)
csv <- data.frame(x = c(181072,181025,181165,181298,181307,181390,181165,181027,181060,181232),
                  y = c(333611,333558,333537,333484,333330,333260,333370,333363,333231,333168),
                  cadmium = c(11.7,8.6,6.5,2.6,2.8,3,3.2,2.8,2.4,1.6))
csv <- as.matrix(csv)
```

Now let's convert it into an asc class object and then export it in the .asc file format...

```
csv <- as.asc(csv)
export.asc(csv, "ASCFILE.asc")
```

Comment: Happy to help, @BappaDas